# Python Pyglet - 'No module named window'

Tags: python, import, module, pyglet, pythonpath

I'm now working on Ubuntu to try and solve this.  I am trying to get Pyglet to work in a .py script.
So, I am using the default install of Python on Ubuntu (2.7.3, Ubuntu v = 12.4).  I used:
sudo apt-get install python-pyglet
and this ran ok.  When I open a terminal, enter 'python' and run

```
import pyglet
import pyglet.window
```

it works.  However, when I have these same two words in a .py, and run that in terminal (by going 'python "path to .py"' I get:

```
  File "/home/parallels/Documents/Google/computer-vision/pyglet.py", line 3, in <module>
    import pyglet
  File "/home/parallels/Documents/Google/computer-vision/pyglet.py", line 4, in <module>
    import pyglet.window
ImportError: No module named window
```

My PYTHONPATH (shown by, in python, entering sys.path is:

```
['', '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7', '/home/parallels', '/usr/lib/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gst-0.10', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntu-sso-client', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-client', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-control-panel', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-couch', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-installer', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-storage-protocol']
```

Does anybody have any idea what is going wrong with the library / installation to make it not work?

Sam

Comment: I forgot to mention, when I did apt-get, the pyglet folder (and other modules I downloaded) got put into /usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your module is named `pyglet.py`. Because of that, the `import` statement looks in your own module for the submodule `window`, where of course it cannot be found. Change the file name of your script and try again.

Comment: Oh dam - I spent 2 days on this and it was so obvious!  Thanks!